# how to disable a function before ajax call, and enable it on ajax success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, click

I have a function is outside of ajax function, I want to disable this "enable" click function while ajax is running, and enable it after ajax successfully loads, how do I approach this exactly? Any help would be appreciated. 
Here is my code:

```
 $('enable').click(function () {
        console.log(123);
        $(this).css('display', 'none');

 var xhr =  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $.vp + "signup/distLookup.ashx" + "?first=" + val_f_name + "&last=" + val_l_name + "&country=" + val_country + "&language=" + $.langID,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) { 
            console.log(data);

    ;
```

Comment: This is not a working snippet, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var enable = true;
$('enable').click(function () {
     if(enable) {
        enable = false;
        console.log(123);
        $(this).css('display', 'none');

         var xhr =  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $.vp + "signup/distLookup.ashx" + "?first=" + val_f_name + "&last=" +     val_l_name + "&country=" + val_country + "&language=" + $.langID,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                enable = true;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

You can set enable to false when the ajax is trigger.

EDIT:

somthing like this?

```
var enable = true;
$('enable').click(function () {
     if(enable) {
        console.log(123);
        $(this).css('display', 'none');
     }
});

function callAjax() {
    enable = false;
    var xhr =  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $.vp + "signup/distLookup.ashx" + "?first=" + val_f_name + "&last=" +     val_l_name + "&country=" + val_country + "&language=" + $.langID,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            enable = true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this only works when the "enable" click function is a trigger of this ajax, what if I want to disable a click function which is outside of this ajax? That means, "function 1" trigger ajax call, while the ajax is running, "function 2" is disabled, then "function 2" enables after ajax on success.

Comment: @7537247 I edit my answer, check if it's what you need.

Comment: It works! Code is easy and simple, also totally makes sense. Greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

if the ajax is inside the click function, then:

```
$('enable').click(function () {
     console.log(123);
     $(this).hide();
     var that=this;         

     var xhr =  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $.vp + "signup/distLookup.ashx" + "?first=" + val_f_name + "&last=" + val_l_name + "&country=" + val_country + "&language=" + $.langID,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) { 
                console.log(data);
                $(that).show();
            }
     });
});
```

else:

```
$('enable').bind('click',function () {
     console.log(123);
     $(this).unbind('click');
});

     var xhr =  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $.vp + "signup/distLookup.ashx" + "?first=" + val_f_name + "&last=" + val_l_name + "&country=" + val_country + "&language=" + $.langID,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) { 
                console.log(data);
                $('enable').bind('click',function () {
                    console.log(123);
                    $(this).unbind('click');
                });
            }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `.one` instead of `.on`, then attach handler on `success`.

```
function sendRequest() {
  var xhr = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $.vp + "signup/distLookup.ashx" + "?first=" + val_f_name + "&last=" + val_l_name + "&country=" + val_country + "&language=" + $.langID,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) { 
      console.log(data);
      $('enable').one('click', sendRequest); // We restore it when get success
    }
}

$('enable').one('click', sendRequest); // once you clicked your handler would be removed
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just have a flag that you can raise when you want to disable the click event:

```
$('enable').click(function () {
    if ($(this).data('disabled')) return;

    $(this).data('disabled', true);

    $.ajax({ ... }).always(function() { $(this).data('disabled', false); }.bind(this));
});
```

Use `.always()` to make sure it is enabled when the ajax request fails as well.